# Google pushes my site to the top when I'm logged into Google

Tags: google, google-search

When I do a search for the product we sell, my site comes number 2 in Google.  However, this only happens when I am searching while also logged into my Google account.

If I start a private browsing session and run **exactly** the same query (even by copying the URL), my site appears down near number 20.

In fact, the order of much of the top 20 sites differs quite significantly?

Could it be that my account is linked to the Google Analytics account for our site?  I'm unsure why Google would exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: Best to use Google Chrome and put it into incognito mode by holding CTRL+SHIFT and N

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I'm asking

Comment: I know that... otherwise I would of added it in an Answer. Its a handy tip for quickly checking REAL organics even when logged in.

Comment: Google search learns your search history and starts tailoring the results to it if you're logged in. It's exactly what you're asking, run incognito if you want to **almost see** what other people see. Not linked to your analytics, just your past.

Comment: *"It's exactly what you're asking"*.  No - it's exactly not.  I am asking **why**, and not how to stop it.  That question is answered perfectly by @dm-guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For long time now, Google adjusts search results according to your search history. You can read about it here:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/54068?hl=en

To check ranking you should use a browser with no history, or a ranking tracking software/service.

Comment: Interesting.  Obviously visiting the site multiple times daily means its pushed me right up there.  Good to know - thanks.